Certificate for gnome-remote-desktop
I'm trying to set up to set-up gnome-remote-desktop installed via dnf onto a Fedora 40 LXC-container.
I've stumbled upon a certificate error.
[root@RemoteDesktop ~]# grdctl rdp enable
[01:08:49:343] [2073:00000819] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - [x509_utils_from_pem]: BIO_new failed for certificate
RDP server certificate is invalid.
Failed to lookup legacy VNC password schema: The name is not activatable

Am I supposed to generate my own cert via OpenSSL and feed it to the server somehow?

Here's the answer: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/headless-remote-desktop-setup-process/20411/2?u=vgaetera
sudo -u gnome-remote-desktop winpr-makecert \
-silent -rdp -path ~gnome-remote-desktop rdp-tls

Needs to be run before the enable.
At least for the problem with the certificate.

While the article under the link may explain the problem, we want to also have the answer right here, in the answer body. Link-only answers, like this one, are discouraged, because the link may rot. However, it's the best if the answer has a link to a respected source of information.

Here is how I configured the certificates
# Create a certificate, decide, if you want to use user-based certs or machine-based. (I guess user based is better, as "grdctl" is configured on a user basis
# These commands are meant to be run for each user individually (and not(!) as root or with sudo):
export GRDCERTDIR=~/.cert
mkdir -p ${GRDCERTDIR}
openssl genrsa -out ${GRDCERTDIR}/grd-tls.key 4096
openssl req -new -key ${GRDCERTDIR}/grd-tls.key -out ${GRDCERTDIR}/grd-tls.csr -subj "/C=DE/ST=Private/L=Home/O=Family/OU=IT Department/CN=ubuntu-live"
openssl x509 -req -days 100000 -signkey ${GRDCERTDIR}/grd-tls.key -in ${GRDCERTDIR}/grd-tls.csr -out ${GRDCERTDIR}/grd-tls.crt

